# Compilation hitting virtual memory limitation in g++ 4.7.1?

Tags: c++, memory, boost, compiler-errors, virtual-memory

I'm compiling some code that makes a heave use of templates (its based on boost::msm framework). When compiled with g++ 4.7.1 the cc1plus process reaches about 2.4 Gb of RAM size and than fails with "virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory" error.

I'm using a 32-bit compiler (switching to 64 bit is not an option ATM), the machine itself is a 64-bit Ubuntu with 16Gb of RAM, the compilation is performed under a 64-bit chroot of Debian wheezy distribution. At the time of compilation there is plenty of RAM available, so if the compilation is to fail because of lack of physically available RAM it is to reach 4Gb first. I tried playing with "ulimit -m" options, setting to different values and setting it to smaller sizes causes the compiler to fail earlier but when left to "unlimited" it fails at the above mentions 2+ Gb.

So I guess something else must be limiting me. Maybe someone encountered a similar issue and knows a way to change the limitation?

Comment: "Switching to 64 bit", do you mean using a 64 bit build of GCC itself or using GCC to build 64 bit executables?

Comment: I meant using 64 bit g++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 32-bit application (including compilers), you typically get somewhere between 2 and 3GB that is available for usermode in virtual space. This is caused by a combination of memory space being reserved, memory space fragmentation (there is virtual memory available, just not a big enough chunk to hold whatever size block that `new` or `malloc` is requesting), and "memory reservation", where process has allocated a fairly large chunk of memory, but it's not actually using all of it, so it's not "populated".

Any particular reason you can't use a 64-bit GCC to generate 32-bit code - using `-M32`? That would be my solution.

Comment: Your explanation suits my observations quite well - the actual size varies. I'll weight using the  64-bit GCC to generate 32-bit code or maybe using some other technique to reduce the compilation size..

Comment: If you are using the same version of gcc in 64-bit, it should produce the same code as the 32-bit build (I've used 32-bit GCC to build 64-bit binaries, at the time when 64-bit OS was in it's infancy, such that you couldn't rely on the compiler to complete in the 64-bit version of the OS!)